# Why is this wont work in BATCH, FOR command? Standallone it works

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch

I want to export images from films, as thumbnail, I'm using `ffmpeg`. My batch command:

```
DEL *.jpg

setlocal
dir *.mp4 /a:-d /b > foldersTemp.txt
FOR /f %%A IN (foldersTemp.txt) DO ffmpeg -i %%A -vf fps=1/200 %%Athumb%04d.jpg
endlocal

DEL foldersTemp.txt
```

but it only creates only one per film. If I use the `ffmpeg` command, it works. I'm afraid the `%` confuses the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file names likely contain spaces.

Add the parameter "tokens=*" to pull the whole line (rather than delimited by a space).  Also, you will also need to surround your output filename with double quotes.

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN (foldersTemp.txt) DO ffmpeg -i %%A -vf fps=1/200 "%%Athumb%%04d.jpg"
```

Comment: yea, and I also had to change to "%%Athumb%%04d.jpg"

Comment: Updated answer with double quotes.

Comment: @Paul consider it escaped.